# MEAN app: Can't receive image on back end, upload fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean-stack

So I'm trying to upload an image to my node.js server. In my component, I have selected the image I want to upload, sent it to my service and then sent it to the server. I did some console.logs to check whether I had received the file.

I wasn't sure if I needed req.body or req.files so I did them both. req.body returns an empty object and req.files returns *undefined*. Does anyone know what I did wrong? I think it has something to do with the request options.

The file I want to upload is a png file.

**This is what the console looks like (with the results from the console.logs from the userService file below**

[image]

**User service file: here I made some console.logs with the results in the console above. I think I need special options here to make the request, but I don't know which ones.**

```
postFile(fileToUpload: File, userId) {
        console.log(fileToUpload);
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
        console.log(formData);
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:3200/user/uploadProfilePicture/" + userId, formData, )
            .map(() => { return true; })
            .catch((e) => this.handleError(e));
    }
```

**node.js back-end: just some console.logs to check if the file arrived at the back-end, which it didn't**

```
router.post('/uploadProfilePicture/:userId', function(req, res){
    console.log('entered');
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);

    res.status(200).json({
        msg: "sup mognol"
    })
});
```

**Results of back-end console.logs**

entered, 
{}, 
undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are sending the files as formData, you need to use node middleware to handle multipart form data.

[Busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) or [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) are both good options

You can use multer like so:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file 
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any 
})
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about those. Thanks! Just one more question. What does the avatar mean in the above code (upload.single('avatar').

Comment: It is the name of the file you send through. So your `req.file` will look like `req.files['avatar'][0] -> File`. The name comes from what you call it in your post request